# Execute javascript in selenium with variable

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Iam trying to execute JavaScript statement which include a variable, How I can pass the variable to the statement

Lang: Python

```
val = "changed"
javaScript = f'document.querySelector("h2").textContent = '"{}"' '.format(val)
driver.execute_script(javaScript)
```

i am getting the below result in chrome which is not what I want

```
document.querySelector("h2").textContent = changed
```

it suppose to be with quotes like this

```
document.querySelector("h2").textContent = "changed"
```

Comment: `javaScript = 'document.querySelector("h2").textContent = "{}" '.format(val)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're trying to use two formatting options at the same time.

If you use at least Python 3.6, then try f-string:

```
val = "changed"
javaScript = f'document.querySelector("h2").textContent = "{val}"'
driver.execute_script(javaScript)
```

or if you want to use `format` function, then (as recommended in comments) remove extra quotes:

```
val = "changed"
javaScript = 'document.querySelector("h2").textContent = "{}"'.format(val)
driver.execute_script(javaScript)
```